# Google analytics with react is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my react project and it doesn't show any active users even when I am online. I have tried different approaches that I found online but none seem to work. I have only tried it on localhost and not on a deployed website but I think it should still work.

Here is my code.

My app.js

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import IntroPage from "./containers/IntroPage/IntroPage";
import Layout from "./containers/Layout/Layout";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Spinner from "./Components/UI/Spinner/Spinner";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

const Contact = React.lazy(() => import("./Components/Contact/Contact"));

const trackingId = "UA-171033255-1";
ReactGA.initialize(trackingId);


function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/contact"
            render={() => (
              <Suspense
                fallback={
                  <div className="Fallback">
                    <Spinner />
                  </div>
                }
              >
                <Contact />
              </Suspense>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/" component={IntroPage} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

Updating from `react-ga` to [`react-ga4`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4) worked for me.

Change the import to `react-ga4` and instead of `ReactGA.pageview(...)` use `ReactGA.send("pageview")`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using empty dependencies array in `useEffect` your code gets executed only once, when `<App/>` rendered. So you are not sending pageviews on route change.

You need to put pageview-related code before your App component, right after ReactGA initialization. It's a usage example from [docs](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the tracking code inside `<head>` in index.html (Admin -> Property -> Tracking code)?

Comment: I don't think that is needed in react.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here -- it seems like the easiest way to associate a GA property with your application. It might be required, too--the react entrypoint is in the `<body>`, and you need to get the tracking snippet into the <head>...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue try disabling your ad block if you have it active and put the ReactGA.initialize inside the useEffect

Answer (score 0):

import ReactGA from "react-ga4";

ReactGA.initialize("your measurement id");
ReactGA.send("pageview");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).