# Google analytics not receiving data from react app

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I am using react-ga to track user navigation through my application. I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/02/17/how-to-integrate-react-app-with-google-analytics.html) to configure GA and my react code. But it is not working, google analytics is not receiving any kind of data.

I would prefer to send data through react library and not manually insert code to the index.html as [some people suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656009/google-analytics-with-react-is-not-working)

my code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    useLocation,
} from "react-router-dom";

import AdminPage from "./admin/adminPage";

import ReactGA from "react-ga";
const TRACKING_ID = "G-EXAMPLE";
ReactGA.initialize(TRACKING_ID);

const App = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
        console.log(location.pathname);
    }, [location.pathname]);

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/admin'>
                <AdminPage />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    );
};
   
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors? What debugging have you done? Also, I am not certain if the `useLocation` hook would see route changes in components below the `App`. It might be better to use a custom history object and `history.listen` for routing changes in a `useEffect` hook. That said, the app/team I work on also had to manually inject the GA script code in the `head` element to get it working.

Comment: there are no errors. I console.log(location.pathname) to check if reactGA.pageview is sent. It is printing in the console everytime I change route, but google analytics is not receiving anything. useLocation is seeing routes changes. @DrewReese

Comment: I see you want to use react-ga which is for traditional Google Universal Analytics, So you need a Tracking ID like UA-xxxxxxx-x.
You can't use the new Google Analytics 4 IDs like the one in your example code.